# Soap fault stacktrace

Tags: java, soap, glassfish

Can anybody help me get the exception stacktrace in the `<detail>` element of SoapFault in glassfish 3.1? By default glassfish 3.0 shows this. And if you want, you can turn off this stacktrace via admin console. But how to show this stacktrace in 3.1?

Answer (score 0):

try this [link](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2418/beaff.html) it is a link to the oracle dev guide. You could also check the galssfish [reference manual](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2433/index.html). this manual is valid for versions 3.1-3.1.1